# I want to add some fields from one table into another table by using one common field as the connector

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a table from which I need to take a few fields and join them into another table by using a common field as the connector.

Table1

```
Bill No   Name                 
1344      cb                    
1434      grer                  
32543     gg                    
1424      gwg                   
14545     gfg
```

Table2

```
Bill No   Age  Address  PhNumber
1344       12   xyz      2345  
32543      16   xyz      8986
1434       14   xyz      5456 
1424       17   xyz      9436
14545      21   xyz      9657
```

I want to join the fields Age, Address and PhNumber from Table 2 into Table1 using BillNo as the link. So I need to add the three fields into Table1 against he correct BillNo.

Result Table needed:

Table1

```
Bill No   Name    Age  Address  PhNumber                
1344      cb      12   xyz      2345                 
1434      grer    14   xyz      5456               
32543     gg      16   xyz      8986              
1424      gwg     17   xyz      9436              
14545     gfg     21   xyz      9657
```

Comment: When you say "add columns from table2 into table1", do you mean "write a query that returns columns from table2 with data from table1"?

Comment: @ Bohemian - It has to return table 1 with BillNo and Name along with Age, Address and Phone number corresponding to the correct BillNo

Comment: It should look something like what? Are you trying to literally add columns to tabke1, or just produce output?

Comment: I need to add the columns literally and update Table 1. It should something like I have shown in the Result Table needed in the question.

Comment: What if there is more than one matching row in table2?

Comment: Google Search .... https://www.google.com.au/search?q=sql+join+wikipedia&oq=sql+join+wikipedia

Comment: Have a look at  SQL Join http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: Dont worry about more than one matching row for now. I just need to join.

Answer (score 1):

Use a join:

```
select t1.bill_no, Name, Age, Address, PhNumber
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.bill_no = t1.bill_no
```

Comment: Hey Bohemian, that did not work. I also want to point out that what I gave is a sample of my table. My original Table1 has got a lot more fields than just Name. Does this mean, I have to list all the frileds in Table1 to join the fields from table2?

Comment: @maash Instead of listing every column, you can use `t1.*` or simply `*` to get all columns of both tables (but of course bill_no will be in there twice). Now, what do you mean by "does not work"?